# Настройка PHP mail()

Tags: php, apache, debian, sendmail

Суть в том, что всё работало как надо. Потом пришлось переустановить PHP и обнаружилось, что перестали отправляться письма. Как оказалось, слетел `sendmail`. После его установки `mail()` заработал, и на отправку письма возвращает `true`, но при этом сами письма не отправляются. Прописан `sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i`.

Почти полностью уверен, что просто где-то не установил какие-то настройки. Не подскажете, где и какие?

Comment: куда ведёт симлинк `/usr/sbin/sendmail`?

Comment: На файл sendmail

Comment: так не бывает. приложите к вопросу, пожалуйста, вывод команды `ls -l /usr/sbin/sendmail`.

Comment: `exim4` процесс работает? Может, оказался настроен на только-локальную работу?

Comment: @Sergiks, возможно, автор вопроса действительно заменил *exim* на *sendmail*. пытаюсь уточнить.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Вывод `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root user 26 Oct 18 22:01 /usr/sbin/sendmail -> /etc/alternatives/sendmail`

Comment: Но на самом деле вопрос уже наверное не актуальный, в чем проблема узнать интересно, но как решение я выбрал использование SMTP и отправку писем напрямую через сервер Яндекса. Так по крайне мере письма на Gmail не попадают в спам. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @Denis оффтопик про спам в gmail, но спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

В качестве почтового сервера предлагаю использовать `Postfix`.

Установка в Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install postfix
```

Выбираем
`Internet Site`

Редактируем `php.ini`

```
sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"
```

Перезапускаем вебсервер. Готово.